# Does the air intake system in a VW CC 2010 go around the engine?

Tags: turbocharger, air-intake, air-filter, maf, intake-manifold

I am trying to visualize what the air intake system in my car looks like.

It's a turbocharged 2.0L VW engine.

As I understand it, the air intake is on the front right near the radiator and headlight. It feeds the air in through the air filter, then the maf sensor (right side near battery) and then passes the turbo charger (at this point we are on the back left of the engine bay).

This is where I get lost as I have never seen the underside of my car.

I know air travels up the intake boot (in front of the radiator), then past the throttle body, into the intake manifold and into the cylinders via the valves.

What happens between the turbo charger (back left of engine bay) and the intake boot/throttle body (front of radiator)?

Does it go around the underside of the engine from the back to the front side?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your description is correct:

> As I understand it, the air intake is on the front right near the radiator and headlight. It feeds the air in through the air filter, then the maf sensor (right side near battery) and then passes the turbo charger (at this point we are on the back left of the engine bay).

Rather than "passing the turbo", the pipe probably curves down and enters the turbo where it is compressed.  The compressed air then goes from the turbo, probably around the front of the engine into an "intercooler" or "charge air cooler" because getting compressed and running through the turbo makes the air hot.  The cooler brings the temp down a bit and the air goes into the intake where it does the usual mix with fuel and explode dance.

If you look up "charge air pipe" for your car you will find pictures of the pipe that goes from the turbo to the intercooler, and maybe where that is located.  Based on my quick search, it runs across the left side of your engine (when facing the car).

Note: I'm not 100% sure your car has an intercooler, but I believe it shares most systems with the Passat of that same age range.

Comment: Beautiful explanation. I understand exactly how the air travels now that I know about the intercooler.